# How to start my application in current screen javafx

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml

how to make my application form start at the current screen?
I have 2 monitors and 1 projector connected to my computer, the projector is my primary screen, I made an application with Javafx and packaged it as a Jar file, lets suppose that I opened the file explorer in screen 2 and I double clicked on the Jar file that I created, now the application starts in the primary screen not screen 2, My question is how to determine the current screen that I started the application with? 
I'm using Javafx with FXML.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Can you explain this a bit more in detail?

Comment: I have 2 monitors and 1 projector connected to my computer, the projector is my primary screen, I made an application with Javafx and packaged it as a Jar file, lets suppose that I opened the file explorer in screen 2 and I double clicked on the Jar file that I created, now the application starts in the primary screen not screen 2, My question is how detriment the current screen that I start the application with?

Comment: It's working, Thanks a lot